# Counting the number of times a pattern appears in a string

Tags: javascript, string

What is the best method for counting the number of times a string appears within a string using JS?

For example:

```
count("fat math cat", "at") returns 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex and then the number of matches can be found from the returned array. This is the naive approach using regex.

```
'fat cat'.match(/at/g).length
```

To protect against cases where the string doesn't match, use:

```
( 'fat cat'.match(/at/g) || [] ).length
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
function count( string, substring ) {
    var result = string.match( RegExp( '(' + substring + ')', 'g' ) ); 
    return result ? result.length : 0;
}
```

Comment: That was my initial stab at it, but unfortunately, if `substring` contains special RegExp characters, it will not work properly.  For example: `count('Count the periods.', '.')` would return `18`.  The caller would have to know to call it like this: `count('Count the periods.', '\.')`

Comment: @Jacob, you can escape RegExp meta-characters from the substring, before building the RegExp object, e.g., something like: `substring.replace(/[[\]{}()*+?.\\|^$\-,&#\s]/g, "\\$&")`...

Comment: Yes, you could.  Still, using `indexOf` with strings is probably more straightforward; RegExp is overkill for this sort of task, and probably slower as a result as well.

Comment: @Jacob Why not create a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) test case and find out which is the fastest solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can use `indexOf` in a loop:

```
function count(haystack, needle) {
    var count = 0;
    var idx = -1;
    haystack.indexOf(needle, idx + 1);
    while (idx != -1) {
        count++;
        idx = haystack.indexOf(needle, idx + 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this, it's overcomplicated:

```
function count(sample, searchTerm) {
  if(sample == null || searchTerm == null) {
    return 0;
  }

  if(sample.indexOf(searchTerm) == -1) {
    return 0;
  }

  return count(sample.substring(sample.indexOf(searchTerm)+searchTerm.length), searchTerm)+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function count(str,ma){
 var a = new RegExp(ma,'g'); // Create a RegExp that searches for the text ma globally
 return str.match(a).length; //Return the length of the array of matches
}
```

Then call it the way you did in your example. `count('fat math cat','at');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` also:

```
function getCount(str,d) {
    return str.split(d).length - 1;
}
getCount("fat math cat", "at"); // return 3
```